# laravel 5.2 error in extending break and continue directive in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use @break  and @continue in my blade template.I try to extending it
this is AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
       Blade::directive('datetime', function($expression) {
            return "<?php echo with{$expression}->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>";
        });
    }
```

But i get this error when i refresh my project

```
FatalErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 16:
Class 'App\Providers\Blade' not found
```

please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have a namespace defined in the beggining of the file. If you didn't specified the namespace of Blade class with `use` statement, it assumes that Blade's namespace is the same as the current file's (`App\Providers`).

**The most simple solution:** put `\` before the `Blade::directive` so it becomes `\Blade::directive`.

Comment: Accept my answer then so everyone can easily find a solution in future.